# Controlling size of TextArea with CloudDeploy FormFunction

Tags: wolfram-cloud, deployment

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormFunction[
  "names" -> 
   RepeatingElement[
    CompoundElement[<|"first" -> "String", "last" -> "TextArea"|>]]]]
```

I am using code like the above to create a web form but the `TextArea` is too small (both width and height). Is there any way to specify the width and height of a `TextArea`?

Comment: FormLayoutFunction may not work with a repeating compound element, but  does it even do what you want for just `FormFunction[{"first" -> "String", "last" -> "TextArea"}]`?

Comment: I am not sure if it can be used for this. I have not found any examples or options modifying width and height directly. I did try to set `"ItemLayout"->"Vertical"` to make the `TextArea` wider. This did not work with `RepeatingElement` +  `CompoundElement`.

Comment: You can examine the page source generated by the Wolfram Development Platform and in principle you could revise this to get exactly the form layout that you desire.